# Index files with English and Greek letters to the same file

Tags: indexing, lucene

Apache Lucene: I have some files with English and Greek letters in the same file.
How do I choose the index analyzer language for indexing both languages? 
I want to search in both languages through the queries.

Answer (score 0):

The StandardAnalyzer - because not specialized to a specific language - fits to all european languages.

Comment: Ok, but when i'm searching my index for Greek words, nothing comes up from it.  Should i user something else and HOW i could choose different analyzer (what should i change to the code)?  Thanks in advance..

Comment: You seem to have an other problem then the analyzer. Maybe provide some code.

Comment: I'm usin luecene Demo for search them.